# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'put' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am facing this issue when i am trying to store data in my angular controller page using the `$cookieStore`. Are there any additional configurations that I have left out ?

```
function fbLogin($cookieStore){

    $cookieStore.put("userid",'12345');
    validateUser(userid);
    alert(userid);
}
```

Comment: What is fbLogin function ? Is it Angular controller ? It sounds like you just call it as a common function, without arguments, which of course means, $cookieStore is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually defining `userId` anywhere to JavaScript.  You're setting a cookie whose value is `userid=12345`, but then calling `validateUser` with an unknown variable, `userId` which has the undefined value.